# How to set:data Gride height and Width

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, wpf-controls

How to set height and width of Data Gide control of WPF to Auto programatically.

Answer (score 0):

To set `Auto` on Width/Height on Elements in code behind you can just set the values to `double.NaN`

```
myControl.Width= double.NaN;
myControl.Height = double.NaN;
```